# React Native: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child - styles

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following simple component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'native-base';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper';
import View from '../../native-base-theme/components/View';
import Button from '../../native-base-theme/components/Button';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  card: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#E8E8E8',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});

class About extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Swiper
          cards={['DO', 'MORE', 'OF', 'WHAT', 'MAKES', 'YOU', 'HAPPY']}
          renderCard={(card) => (
            <View style={styles.card}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{card}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          onSwiped={(cardIndex) => {
            console.log(cardIndex);
          }}
          onSwipedAll={() => {
            console.log('onSwipedAll');
          }}
          cardIndex={0}
          backgroundColor="#4FD0E9"
          stackSize={3}
        >
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('oulala');
            }}
            title="Press me"
          >
            You can press me
          </Button>
        </Swiper>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

Not sure why I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {.padder}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

According to the react debugger, the issue is in this line:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
```

As far as I understand I pass object to the style property, but in all examples I have checked it is valid, so what I am missing?

Comment: Can you also add your import statements?

Comment: @AtinSingh Added

Comment: Can you add the code of View and Button that you have imported?

Comment: @AtinSingh Thanks! I imported those components from the wrong place. NO idea why the editor suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your button to this. You can't pass any children to a button.

```
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('oulala');
        }}
        title="You can press me"
      />
```

Comment: Didn't help, same issue :(